# WHEN run query it take too much time although it return small number or records?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, stored-procedures, sql-execution-plan

I work on SQL server 2012 I face issue when run query below it take 9 minutes to return 900 rows only

```
SELECT fmat.Value as PLID,c.CodeTypeId,
COUNT(DISTINCT tr.PartID) [#partsHasCodes]
into #partsHasCodes
FROM Parts.TradeCodes tr WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Parts.Nop_Part pt WITH(NOLOCK) ON pt.PartID = tr.PartID
INNER JOIN Parts.Nop_PartsFamilyAttribute fmat WITH(NOLOCK) ON  fmat.PartFamilyID=pt.PartsFamilyID AND fmat.[Key]=20281007
inner join #TempPlAndCodeType c on (c.CodeTypeId=tr.CodeTypeID)
GROUP BY fmat.Value,c.CodeTypeId
```

What I have tried:

this is execution plan :

```
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJXDEp_bv
```

Add cluster index to #TempPlAndCodeType:

```
create clustered index idx on #TempPlAndCodeType (CodeTypeId)
```

but still take too much time

so what I do to enhance query at least minimize time ?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a lot of rows before applying filtering. You can change the `joins` order and use `force the join order` by hint, but it will be better to simplify the query. Could you try this?

```
CREATE TABLE #Buffer
(
    [PartID] BIGINT PRIMARY KEY-- or the type it is
)

INSERT INTO #Buffer ([PartID])
SELECT DISTINCT pt.PartID
FROM Parts.Nop_Part pt WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Parts.Nop_PartsFamilyAttribute fmat WITH(NOLOCK) 
    ON  fmat.PartFamilyID=pt.PartsFamilyID 
    AND fmat.[Key]=20281007;

SELECT fmat.Value as PLID
      ,c.CodeTypeId
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT tr.PartID) [#partsHasCodes]
into #partsHasCodes
FROM Parts.TradeCodes tr WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN #Buffer pt WITH(NOLOCK) 
    ON pt.PartID = tr.PartID
inner join #TempPlAndCodeType c 
    on c.CodeTypeId = tr.CodeTypeID
GROUP BY fmat.Value
        ,c.CodeTypeId;
```

The idea is to filter by the `Parts.Nop_PartsFamilyAttribute` table first to get the needed `partid`s. Then, to extract the data. You can see from the screenshot below, that you are starting with read of 50 millions rows and allocating ~700 mb memory. Then, after the filtration by the `Parts.Nop_PartsFamilyAttribute` table, we are getting only 14 millions.

[image]